# Querying workload tags in Google Earth Engine: Discrepancy in EECU consumption between tags

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/cloud/api_monitoring#workload-tags) on adding workload tags while working with Google Earth Engine. The example in the documentation demonstrates the use of two tags, `compositing` and `exports`. However, in my script, I opted for `compositing` and `export-to-assets` as tags. I am currently facing an issue when querying the workload tags, as the EECU seconds seem to be disproportionately allocated between `export-to-assets` and `compositing`. I have provided an excerpt from my task below, along with relevant details:

```yaml
Phase: Completed
Runtime: 1h (started 2023-07-21 15:24:30 +0700)
Attempted 1 time
Batch compute usage: 674590.5000 EECU-seconds
```

```js
ee.data.setWorkloadTag('compositing');

ee.data.setWorkloadTag('topo-correction');

// Applying topographic correction to images collection
var correctedTopo = landsatColScaled.map(topoCorrection);

ee.data.setWorkloadTag('brdf-correct');

// Applying BRDF correction function
var brdfCol = correctedTopo.map(brdfCorrect);

ee.data.setWorkloadTag('mask-cloud');

// Applying cloud masking function
var cloudMasked = brdfCol.map(maskCloudLandsatOli);

// .....

  ee.data.setWorkloadTag('export-to-assets');

  // Export image
  var desc = name;
  var project = exportAddress;
  Export.image.toAsset({
    image: Composite, 
    description: desc, 
    assetId: project + desc,
    region: aoi, 
    scale: 30, 
    crs: 'EPSG:4326', 
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  
  ee.data.resetWorkloadTag(true);
```

As seen above, all the EECU seconds appear to be spent on `export-to-assets`, with only a small amount allocated to computation. I am unsure if I have set up the workload tags correctly. If I have, I am curious to know why the `export-to-assets` task consumes such a significant amount of EECU seconds compared to the `computation`.

[image: workload tag for export]

What is the cause of this discrepancy and how can I appropriately assess the performance of my tasks based on the chosen workload tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how tags work.  All the actual work happens during the export; you can't tag individual pieces in the middle.  You submit one big computational description as part of the Export, and everything gets assigned to the last tag.